# how to run Hbase and Hadoop mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, nosql, hbase

Can any one tell me how to compile and run Hbase and Hadoop mapreduce. I have been searching it for more than a day. And i have tried something and  end up with the following error

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471552/hbase-on-windows-executing-java-program

Can any one give me solution or a reference

Thanks

Comment: Hmmm .. @PandiyanCool... Instead try to solve the problem

Comment: Am not familiar with java .anyway hope this link helps http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/package-summary.html

Comment: can you narrow down your question:
do you have problems specifically on windows? did you narrow ddown the problem to be a windows problem? what exactly do you want? map reduce? hbase client? map-reduce with hbase input? did you succeed in running simple samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDFS/Hadoop is not compatible on windows, there is a cygwin approach for windows but its not complete. You will save tons of your time and effort running hadoop on Linux.

Check the examples for Hbase MR on Hbase site:
http://hbase.apache.org/book/mapreduce.example.html
I use CDH libraries, below link guides you how to setup the maven dependencies:
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH-Version-and-Packaging-Information/cdhvd_topic_8.html

Basically you will need 3 libraries: hadoop-client (hadoop-core/hadoop-common) zookeeper and hbase (hbase-common) to compile your Hbase map reduce program.

Answer (score 1):

I also discourage you from the usage of HBase on windows. If you still try it, use [this tutorial](http://hbase.apache.org/cygwin.html).

I've not tried it and I think you really should consider working on a virtual machine (if you just want to get your feet wet with the technology).

Use, for example, [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) for a virtual environment on your Windows machine. Then install a Linux distribution like Ubuntu as a VM. There you can easily install Hadoop and HBase.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Hortonworks [HDP for Windows](http://hortonworks.com/products/hdp-windows/)? They claim it is open source and it looks like they provide at least minimally needed set of documentation for developers. So I think it is moreless doable and more, advice you at least to try their approach.

My own approach for 'trail' development is to use Cloudera [Hadoop distribution](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products-and-services/cdh.html) over any Ubuntu/CentOS VM on Windows host (lot of options for guest VM [including their own free bundle](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/DemoVMs/Cloudera-QuickStart-VM/cloudera_quickstart_vm.html)). [Cloudera Manager](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products-and-services/cloudera-manager.html) (which has free 'standard' edition) simplifies initial setup. Actually they look like 'standard de facto' if you need good enough solution with reasonable level of documentation and it should be free while it is small.

Having Hadoop installed on VM you can access it based on any of large set of client libraries. I don't recommend actually to have Hadoop server on Windows. At least for some time from now (end of 2013).

OK, with 'pure' Apache solution everything looks much more complex.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is running hadoop and HBASE on windows, note that the "old" method of using cygwin is preety hard - especially if you want to set up a cluster, and not just use local mode.

as noted above, Hortonworks have a windows version, but it requires a windows server OS.
a similar option is use the Microsoft version (which was also developed by Hortonworks - it's probably just different packaging) which is called [hdinsight](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn247618.aspx) and supports also desktop windows versions (although it's limited to a single host)

If this isn't your problem, you should define it more clearly